# Get all sequential block from a list

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a list of number in mysql like that

```
column 1       column2            column 3
4 
6
7 
88
21
29
30 
31
```

How can i get all sequential blocks, result should be

```
6
7
29
30
31
```

Comment: What are you showing three columns, but values only in the first?

Comment: Do you want the sorting based on all the three columns or just the first column?

Comment: Just use order by, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to it using self-join and `union`.

```
select t1.val
from t t1
join t t2 on t1.val = t2.val-1
union
select t2.val
from t t1
join t t2 on t1.val = t2.val-1
order by 1
```

Edit: I realized this could be done with a single query instead of using `union`.

```
select distinct t1.val
from t t1
join t t2 on t1.val = t2.val-1 or t1.val = t2.val+1
order by 1
```

Comment: This one performs better.

Comment: It shouldn't perform better on larger data sets, because of the overhead in removing duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff..i totally agree with you..your solution is faster

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.col1 = t.col1 + 1
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.col1 = t.col1 - 1
             ) ;
```

You can combine the `exists` into a single subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.col1 in (t.col1 - 1, t.col1 + 1)
             );
```

The first version should be able to make use of an index on the column.  It might be more difficult for an optimize to use an index for the second.

Also note that these versions allow you to include other columns from the rows as well.

Comment: First query doesn't use the index. You should change to `where t2.col1 = t.col1 + 1`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b4134/5

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to sort just to get the values of your first column, if not I would love to edit my answer. So if you just need the values of first column, here is how u can do it:

```
SELECT column1 
FROM  `table` 
ORDER BY  `column1` ASC
```

You can use the direction of sorting as desired.

Comment: @tomen, I am afraid it is then not clear what you want, can you reframe ur question.

Comment: The OP wants to identify the "runs" (increasing numbers), i.e. the rows where `id(row_n+1)+1` equals `id(row_n)`, like 6,7 and 29,30,31. The 4, for example has no predecessor (3) and no successor (5), so it's left out.