# Find sequential of string

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to find all sequential numbers from 1 column with the code below.
There is problem cause col1 has type string, so i can't do any math calculation.
Has anyone solution for this?

```
select t.*
    from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col1 in (t.col1 - 1, t.col1 + 1)
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use min() and max() or sorting and limit 1 to determine the values next to a given value. The values will not necessarily be +1/-1 from the starting point, since values may be missing, or the textual part of the id may change. Min/max is better if you are looking for such values accross a set of records.

For all col1 values:

```
select t1.col1, max(t2.col1), min(t3.col1)
from t t1
left join t t2 on t1.col1>t2.col1
left join t t3 on t1.com1<t2.col1
group by t1.col1
```

You can join table t 2x more to get the data for the other col1 values from t.

For a particular col1 value:

```
select * from t where col1>'specific value' order by col1 asc limit 1
union
select * from t where col1<'specific value' order by col1 desc limit 1
```

Comment: Are you sure about min(t3.col) , i have always error with that. And i want to find sequential blocks(could be 3, 4 or more sequential numbers) not just 2 sequential number

Comment: If you want to include more than one on the side, then you cannot use min and max approach, you need to go with the order by and limit approach. They will not necessarily be consecutive items.

Comment: can you show me the code, I still don't understand how it works

Comment: Instead of limit 1, have limit 3 or 4.

Comment: no i want all sequetial blocks (as long as squential, it'll be included), not just limit by 3 or 4. see my example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677519/get-all-sequential-block-from-a-list?noredirect=1

Comment: Then just split the col1 to have a string and a numeric part and apply the increase to the numeric part only and join it up again.